# How to view attached PNG images in Bugzilla web-browser page?

Tags: windows-vista, bugzilla

I attached image to the bug in Bugzilla (version 3.2.4).

When I press details near the attachment I am not able to view picture in the web-browser, I need to download it.

The message on the page I obtain is following:
"The attachment is not viewable in your browser due to security restrictions enabled by Bugzilla.
In order to view the attachment, you first have to download it."

I use Windows Vista x32.

**How should I configure Bugzilla to view attached images?**

Thanks!

*P.S. If superuser is inappropriate place for such kind of questions I would like to ask to redirect me to correct place (stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com, ...?)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the Parameters, specifically the Attachments section.